# Segmentation fault in ./libobjc.so.2

Tags: objective-c, linux, segmentation-fault

When I launch my program on Linux with gdb I have this message;

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00007ffff3bc7315 in objc_msg_lookup () from ./libobjc.so.2

Could you tell me please where it could come from (what type of error in my code does it indicate)?
Thank you!

Comment: What does the rest of the backtrace look like?

Comment: How I can have the rest of the backtrace ? 
I have the message Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64 but I don't manage to install it because "it could not be found"

Comment: I have no idea;  I haven't done ObjC on Linux w/gdb in a couple of decades.   It sounds like, though, that you don't have a complete stack installed and you are missing some major components.

Comment: My program (my company's program to be exact) works fine on MacOS, but crashes on linux. I know that it is linked to the data stored into the database because if I use another dump it woks fine on Linux. I suspect an encodage error (russian client), but no idea where to search.

Comment: There are some pretty radical differences between ObjC on OS X and iOS. Potentially, anyway.  This kind of error is usually caused by a prematurely deallocated object.  I'd suggest starting by fixing your dev tools chain so you can get backtraces as that would, at least, indicate everything is working end to end (that you have a working database file is great).  From there, things like character encodings and the like may cause encoding issues.  Hard to say.